# Why is working locally so important and variations are considered small?

Tags: linear-systems

In most places, whenever a function is expanded whether it is Hooke's Law and harmonic oscillators in Quantum Mechanics, expansion of Lagrangian terms in Action Principle of Least Action, Einstein-Hilbert Action and since I'm studying Killing Vectors I can see it in that too as only linear variations in metric are considered to define Killing Vector. So this and more examples span whole Physics.

Why is it that physics is so bent upon defining everything locally? Are variations always small or is there something more deep? Also, can these results derived from linear variations be extended simply to higher order variations or require working from the beginning itself?